# Full TargetPlatform to be able to use the xtext editor

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext, target-platform

I need to integrate xtext with other Eclipse based tool (based on RCP plugins).
I have used as example the target platform provided in the eclipse example xtext project:
[image]
[image]

If I use the target platform from org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.releng I see no errors in my workspace. Target platform:
[image]

After setting the Target Platoform and run Eclipse runtime app, I am not able to use the xtext editor in my Eclipe runtime instance.

EDIT:
I cannot open with Domainmodel editor after changing the Target Platform:
[image]

Comment: By "Eclipse runtime app" you mean a runtime launched from Eclipse IDE? Can you check which plug-ins are included in the runtime (Run > Run Configurations... > Select your application > Plug-ins tab)? I usually use the "Launch with: all workspace and enabled target plug-ins" option. Besides that, what do you mean by "not able to use the Xtext editor"? It isn't used by default when you open a file using your extension? An error is thrown?

Comment: "Eclipse runtime app" you mean a runtime launched from Eclipse IDE >> yes; "not able to use the Xtext editor"? It isn't used by default when you open a file using your extension -> shall be used by default but after setting the target platform with the xtext dependecies from the post picture, my gramaire is no longer processed in the launched eclipse.

Comment: Have you checked whether the domainmodel plug-ins are part of the runtime? Do you have the "Domainmodel Editor" option when right-click > Open With on a _.dmodel_ file?

Comment: No, I cannot open with "Domainmodel Editor" after changing TP.

Comment: The target platform may actually be flawed: tons of errors show up when launching an Eclipse runtime on 2019-12 (which you seem to use) to basically complain about unresolved dependencies. Don't you have such errors when launching the runtime application? If you face them as well I crafted a little target platform which should work and which I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Yes, there are tons of error. If you have a TP file I think it may be useful. I have a lot of errors but my application lunches though. Thanks :)

Comment: Please report such errors next time: they are often important to understand and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target platform may actually be flawed: tons of errors are shown when launching an Eclipse runtime on 2019-12 (which you seem to use).

It may be caused by the `includeMode="slicer"` which tells PDE not to fetch additional dependencies. I crafted the following target platform which seems to work well:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde?>
<target name="Xtext Domainmodel Example - Eclipse 2019-12" sequenceNumber="1526502000">
  <locations>
      <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
          <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-12"/>
          <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="2.20.0.v20191028-0905"/>
          <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="3.18.200.v20191210-0610"/>
          <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.feature.group" version="4.14.0.v20191210-0610"/>
          <unit id="org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group" version="2.20.0.v20191202-1256"/>
      </location>
  </locations>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was useful. I needed to download XText from its update site, I posted below the TP that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The target platform below worked for me, used xtext 2.21:

```
<target name="Xtext Domainmodel Example - Eclipse Photon" sequenceNumber="1526501985">
  <locations>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
      <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-12"/>
    </location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
      <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
      <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emft/mwe/updates/releases/2.11.2"/>
    </location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
        <unit id="org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group" version="0.0.0"/>
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/releases/2.21.0/"/>
    </location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.objectweb.asm" version="7.2.0.v20191010-1910"/>
      <unit id="org.objectweb.asm.tree" version="7.2.0.v20191010-1910"/>
      <unit id="com.google.inject" version="3.0.0.v201605172100"/>
      <unit id="org.apache.commons.cli" version="1.2.0.v201404270220"/>
      <unit id="com.google.guava" version="27.1.0.v20190517-1946"/>
      <unit id="io.github.classgraph" version="4.8.35.v20190528-1517"/>
      <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/2019-12"/>
    </location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
      <unit id="org.eclipse.draw2d.feature.group" version="3.10.100.201606061308"/>
      <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/legacy/releases"/>
    </location>
  </locations>
</target>
```